# How can I optimize this query which works with 24M row table?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have a table with 24 milion rows.

I want to run this query:

```
select r1.userID, r2.userID, sum(r1.rate * r2.rate) as sum
from dbo.Ratings as r1 
join dbo.Ratings as r2
on r1.movieID = r2.movieID
where r1.userID <= r2.userID
group by r1.userID, r2.userID
```

As I tested, it took 24 hours to produce 0.02 percent of the final result.

How can I speed it up?

**Here is the definition of the table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ratings](
    [userID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [movieID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [rate] [real] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [userID] ASC,
    [movieID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_RatingsMovies] ON [dbo].[Ratings]
(
    [movieID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_RatingsUsers] ON [dbo].[Ratings]
(
    [userID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Here is the execution plan:**

[image: execution plan]

Comment: You probably have already done this, but just in case: if you select 'display estimated execution plan' instead of executing the query will have SQL Server suggesting helpful indexes.

Comment: When you look at the execution plan, which index is it using, if any?

Comment: I added the execution plan image. But I don't know how to find helpful index

Comment: I was hoping that SQL Server would automatically offer a helpful index for you... Obviously this is not the case.

Comment: By the way, IX_RatingsUsers on UserID is probably redundant, since you already have a clustered index on (UserID, MovieID).

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis that was helpful in other queries.

Comment: Not an answer to the question but why is rate using the real datatype? Shouldn't you be using an exact datatype like numeric? How many rows does this return?

Comment: Although it seems silly, I would try to create a "reverse" index including the rate column: `CREATE INDEX IX_Ratings_Reverse on Ratings(movieid, userid) include(rate);` (because obviously this query would be very well serviced by such a *clustered* index).

Comment: And if SQL Server ignores this index, use a `HINT` to force its use.

Comment: I don't think the problem is 24million rows, I think it's that your joining the table to itself with a non-unique key, so this means your derived dataset is potentially many times that size.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis What do you mean by using a Hint?

Comment: @SeanLange I used real because I have 24 milion rows which uses 500 mega byte storage.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. I would assume the rating is a whole between 1 and 5 or something like that? A real uses 4 bytes of storage. You could use tinyint instead which uses 1 byte of storage and is an exact value.

Comment: @SeanLange No rating is between -5 and 5 and it is normalized with normal distribution. that the average is 0

Comment: Index hints are "powerful, yet potentially dangerous", so before going there try the reverse index and let us know how it goes.

Comment: So then use a small int. That is only 2 bytes. But whatever...that is not part of the issue here.

Comment: @Giorgosatlantis no it does not use the reverse index.

Comment: Well, it's hint time... 'select r1.userID, r2.userID, sum(r1.rate * r2.rate) as sum
from dbo.Ratings as r1 
join dbo.Ratings as r2 with (index(IX_Ratings_Reverse))
on r1.movieID = r2.movieID
where r1.userID <= r2.userID
group by r1.userID, r2.userID
'

Comment: If you join every movie-user row to every other movie-user row, your 24 million rows will expand exponentially.  What result are you wanting?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis it works great! write an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: I am very glad to hear it, though I wasn't so optimistic... Rarely is a hint helpful, because the optimiser is supposed to know better. Unless the statistics were outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I suggested was to create a "reverse" index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Ratings_Reverse on Ratings(movieid, userid) include(rate);
```

and then force SQL Server to use it:

```
select r1.userID, r2.userID, sum(r1.rate * r2.rate) as sum 
from dbo.Ratings as r1 join dbo.Ratings as r2 
with (index(IX_Ratings_Reverse)) 
on r1.movieID = r2.movieID 
where r1.userID <= r2.userID group by r1.userID, r2.userID
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that might help.

1)  Change the order of columns in your clustered index to `MovieID,UserID`.  This would group all the same MovieID's together first, which might change your Hash Match to an Inner Loop, and improve the performance of the JOIN.

2)  Change the [IX_RatingsMovies] index to INCLUDE UserID and Rate.   The more I think about it, I think this is less likely than my first suggestion to help.  But it's possible.

Comment: Well, this is a nice sum-up of the comments under the question :-)